# ReactJS - passing parameters to functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I struggle with passing parameters to the `onToggleOpen` function - I render multiple markers (here only 2 for simplifying) and when I click on a marker, I want to display the respective `InfoWindow` for it. But when I click on the marker now, the method `onToggleOpen` is not triggered.

If I remove the indexes from markers and also from `onToggleOpen`, then the functionality of displaying and hiding `InfoWindow` boxes - but then all `InfoWindow` boxes will open and hide at the same time.

How do I properly pass the index to `onToggleOpen`?

```
const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
  >
    <Marker 
        key='1'
        position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} 
        onClick={props.onToggleOpen(1)}
    >
        {props.isOpen && 
            <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                <div>Something 1</div>
            </InfoWindow>
        }
    </Marker>
    <Marker 
        key='2'
        position={{ lat: -33.867855, lng: 151.178897 }} 
        onClick={props.onToggleOpen(2)}
    >
        {props.isOpen && 
            <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                <div>Something 2</div>
            </InfoWindow>
        }
    </Marker>
  </GoogleMap>
))
export default class GoogleMapsSample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          isOpen: false
        }
        this.onToggleOpen = this.onToggleOpen.bind(this);
    }

    onToggleOpen(index){
        console.log('x');
        //this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
        if (this.state.isOpen === index) {
            this.state.isOpen = false;
        } else {
            this.state.isOpen = index;
        }
        console.log(this.state.isOpen);
    }

    render() {
        const { isOpen } = this.state;
        console.log('isOpen: ', this.state.isOpen);
        return (
            // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
            <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
                <MyMapComponent 
                    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyDFD30jUKH0Cl8qrZoNCe-eEGQBIfApzE0"
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                    onToggleOpen={this.onToggleOpen}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I am not sure that the attribute `isOpen` is changed here

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
    this.onToggleOpen = this.onToggleOpen.bind(this);
}
```

...

```
<Marker 
    key='1'
    position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} 
    onClick={()=>props.onToggleOpen(1)}
>
    {props.isOpen === 1 && 
        <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
            <div>Something 1</div>
        </InfoWindow>
    }
</Marker>
```

because the `InfoWindow` block is never executed. I thought that in the function where I change the state is something wrong:

```
onToggleOpen(index){
    //this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
    if (this.state.isOpen === index) {
        this.state.isOpen = false;
    } else {
        this.state.isOpen = index;
    }
}
```

but here the `this.state.isOpen` attribute is properly changed (tested with `console.log`). But even though here is `isOpen` is changed, the `InfoWindow` is never displayed after clicking on the marker.

I have also tried to set its value in contructor like this:

```
this.state = {
  isOpen: false
}
```

and the `InfoWindow` is displayed after loading the page, but when I click on the marker, nothing happens with the `InfoWindow`, it will not disappear and stays displayed (even though the values in `onToggleOpen()` are properly changed).

What am I overlooking here? Am I passing the value `isOpen` incorrectly to the `Marker`?

Comment: Does your Map component only ever have Two Markers? Or is it going to be dynamic, and have many markers? The way you are doing it now, and hardcoding values into each one is not a wise, and scaleable idea.

Comment: It will have many markers, but for simplifying, I only put to the script 2 markers.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich it looks like props.onToggleOpen is passed correctly, but I think that props.isOpen is not passed properly, because the changed attribute is not reflected in the Marker. I have edited the OP to show the issue. Thank you

Comment: You should never directly mutate the state object. You are doing so when you say this.state.isOpen = whatever. You need to use this.setState so React knows to trigger a rerender.

Comment: There is never any case where you should not be using setState

Comment: Oh I spent almost 2 hours thinking about this, totally forgot about `this.setState({ isOpen: index });`.  Still new to React, so it takes me time to put the newly learned things in place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by writing `props.onToggleOpen(1)` you are actually calling the function there. but i think you need it to be called when the marker is clicked.

so the correct code of the `Marker` component should be the following:

```
<Marker 
    key='1'
    position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} 
    onClick={()=>props.onToggleOpen(1)}
>
    {props.isOpen && 
        <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
            <div>Something 1</div>
        </InfoWindow>
    }
</Marker>
```

notice `()=>props.onToggleOpen(1)`. now this will call `onToggleOpen` when you click the marker.

Comment: Inline arrow function will work. This should give him what he needs.

Comment: @InusSaha, @DanielZuzevich it looks like `props.onToggleOpen` is passed correctly, but I think that `props.isOpen` is not passed properly, because the changed attribute is not reflected in the `Marker`. I have edited the OP to show the issue. Thank you